# CSS Styling of a tooltip in a TH tag

Tags: css, jqgrid

I am trying to style a tooltip in a jqgrid in a page delivered through AngularJS.  Essentially in other places in the app I am using the Bootstrap tooltip styling.  I'm struggling to get this to work in the AngularJS part (possibly to do with the initialisation not running in the right place).  I thought I might change tack and try to emulate the styling instead.

I have started and got a very rough and ready bit of styling almost 'working' as a PoC (it needs a lot of work buit I want to see if it is possible before doing that work!  It is here in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w72q7nzv/2/)

I have 2 questions I wondered if anyone could help me with before I try to tidy it up

1) Is there a way to stop the normal tooltip appearing as well (I thought I was styling the tooltip but I seem to be adding a second one!)

2) Is there a way to make it 'float'.  In the fiddle it is not obvious but in the jqgrid where the th element is more structured (bounded) the css tooltip I have created is contained in the th element and mainly hidden (as it is too large for the element).

I'm thinking this is a CSS question more than a jqgrid question so just in case I'll point out I can't really use the span technique posted in a few answers.

Thanks.

The code in the fiddle is

```
<table>
  <th title="This is a tooltip">John</th>
  <th title="so is this">Albert</th>
  <th title="And This">Spencer</th>
</table>

th[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All you need to do is change from title attribute to data-title so it would be: `content: attr(data-title);` Then also update the th title attribute accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that's a interesting tip.  It answers half the question but the resulting 'tooltip' is still bounded by the th element in the jqGrid.  After playing about a bit more I realise that this is an unreasonable ask though as the behaviour is caused by levels within levels of the jqgrid css.  I'll need to play with this a bit more I think to get to the root cause.